# Determine if 2 eigenvectors are orthogonal.

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, orthogonality

Let
$$
T:V \to V
$$
Be a linear operator.

And:

$$
0 \neq u,v \in V
$$

Such that:

$$
T(v) = \lambda_1v, \quad T(u) = \lambda_2u
$$

NOTE: It may be that $\lambda_1 = \lambda_2$

The question asks what are the conditions in which it holds that: 
$$
(u,v) = 0
$$

Now i have the following options:

1. If $T$ is normal
2. Only if $T$ is normal
3. Only if $T$ is normal and $\lambda_1 \neq \lambda_2$
4. All the answers are incorrect

### What i think:

If $T$ is normal, eigenvectors of different eigenvalues are orthogonal.

Therefore, it must hold that if $3$ holds, so $(u,v) = 0$

Yet, maybe can i say more? Am i missing something?

Answer (score 1):

Normal only $(\lambda_1=\lambda_2)$ does not garantee  $(u,v)=0$, for exemple suppose as given $\lambda_1=\lambda_2=\lambda$, $$ T(v) = \lambda v, \quad T(u) = \lambda u$$ and $(u,v)=0$ take $w=u+v$  then also $T(v) = \lambda v, \quad T(w) = \lambda w$ but $(v,w)\neq 0$, to have a certain orthogonality $T$ normal and $\lambda_1\neq \lambda_2$.

(For  normal matrices there exist a set of orthonormal eigenvectors)

Now the answer here could be four as one can easily construct non normal matrices of dimension $n>2$ having only two orthogonal eigenvectors